# How to make picasso reload all pictures

Tags: image, reload, picasso

I have basically recreated picasso's simple project with grid view. Since my pictures are a live feed from a camera from internet, i would like somehow to make picasso to reload them. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be calling the

```
Picasso.with(context).invalidate();
```

method. This "*invalidate[s] all memory cached images*".

Another solution would be providing Picasso with your own `LruCache` implementation (by simply extending [this class](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/LruCache.java) and passing it to the constructor).

When you want to reload all the images, simply clear the cache (either by calling `clear()` or `evictAll()` and invalidate the adapter, so that images are fetched all over again.